# Text inside span is getting cut (hidden) while using bt btn-block

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Text inside a span is getting cut, I tried using float:left but this does not work.
[image]

Here is the fiddle for the same, https://jsfiddle.net/eeha22vk/.

Not able to provide all the output HTML as it's quite lengthy.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1 text-center xsmalltext" style="margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:10px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding-top:5px; padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
        <div class="btn-group btn-block">
            <span id="MainContent_GridViewBVDVSavedTemplate_fldItemHeader_0" title="XXX-27,2017-27,2017" class="btn btn-info btn-sm col-sm-12" style="float:left">XXX-27,2017-27,2017</span>
        </div>
        <table id="r_0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span id="z0" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm col-sm-12" style="font-size:1rem;line-height:1.8rem;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">A</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span id="z1" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm col-sm-12" style="font-size:1rem;line-height:1.8rem;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">B</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span id="z2" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm col-sm-12" style="font-size:1rem;line-height:1.8rem;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">C</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Comment: What would you like to happen - should the text to wrap? Or should the cell resize to fit?

Comment: Because `span` has `.btn` class and in `btn` class there's `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, The cell should resize to fit the content.

Comment: @locateganesh, If I set white-space to pre-line , it's shifting the cells and that showing wrong data